# flutter: transform path in CustomPaint with Float64List Matrix4

Tags: flutter, graphics, flutter-layout

I was trying to rotate some path and did not find a snippet and matrix4 in general is not well documented. So in case someone else has this problem, this is what I ended up with

Answer (score 5):

First of all, [here is a nice read](https://medium.com/flutter-community/advanced-flutter-matrix4-and-perspective-transformations-a79404a0d828) about the math behind it and how to use matrix4.

In my demo I used an arrow tip. Since sequence matters, I paint it at (0,0), then I rotate it around the z-axis and finally I move the tip to the requested spot.

```dart
Path _getArrow (Offset offset, double alpha) {
    Path a = Path();
    a.moveTo(ARROWSIZE, - ARROWSIZE);
    a.lineTo(0, 0);
    a.lineTo(ARROWSIZE, ARROWSIZE);
    final translateM = Float64List.fromList([
        1,             0,     0, 0,
        0,             1,     0, 0,
        0,             0,     1, 0,
        offset.dx, offset.dy, 0, 1]
    );
    final rotateM = Float64List.fromList([
       cos(alpha), sin(alpha), 0, 0,
      -sin(alpha), cos(alpha), 0, 0,
           0,         0,       1, 0,
           0,         0,       0, 1]
    );
    final b = a.transform(rotateM);
    final c = b.transform(translateM);

    return c;

  }
```